# updating mysql from html table using jquery to ajax to php

Tags: php, html, jquery, json, ajax

i want to loop through my html table rows then update my mysql table using the first column as an id in html table
ihave tried this code but it update all rows using only the first row.

heres my code to create a and append a table; id="editable "

```
   $.ajax({
            url: "editqryclass.php",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "post",
            data:{branchedit: $("#branchedit").val(),datetoday: $("#datetoday").val(),sayt:1},
            success: function(response){

            var len = response.length;
            for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                var tr_strs = "<tr id='row1'>" +
                "<td align='center' style='white-space: nowrap;'>" + response[i].memid + "</td>" +
                "<td align='center' style='white-space: nowrap;'>" + response[i].account + "</td>" +
                "<td align='center' style='white-space: nowrap;'>" + response[i].name + "</td>" +
                "<td align='center' style='white-space: nowrap;'>" + response[i].kindsofloan + "</td>" +
                "<td align='center' style='white-space: nowrap;'>" + response[i].loan_balance + "</td>" +
                "<td align='center' style='white-space: nowrap;'><select name='brselect' id='brselect'>" +
                        "<option value='With Collateral'>With Collateral</option>"+
                        "<option value='Without Collateral'>Without Collateral</option>"+
                        "</select></td>" +
                "<td align='center' style='white-space: nowrap;'><select name='abawt' id='abawt'>" +
                        "<option value='Able and Willing to Pay'>Able and Willing to Pay</option>"+
                        "<option value='Not able but willing to Pay'>Not able but willing to Pay</option>"+
                        "<option value='Able but no willing to pay'>Able but no willing to pay</option>"+
                        "<option value='Not able and not willing to pay'>Not able and not willing to pay</option>"+
                        "</select></td>" +
                "<td align='center' style='white-space: nowrap;'><input type='text' id='wattodo' value=" + response[i].whattodo + "></td>" +
                "<td align='center' style='white-space: nowrap;'><input type='text' id='whentodo' value=" + response[i].whentodo + "></td>" +
                "<td align='center' style='white-space: nowrap;'><input type='text' id='colector' value=" + response[i].collector + "></td>" +
                "<td align='center' style='white-space: nowrap;'><input type='text' id='remark' value=" + response[i].remark + "></td>" +
                "<td align='center' style='white-space: nowrap;'><select name='coltype' id='coltype'>" +
                        "<option value='Easy Collection'>Easy Collection</option>"+
                        "<option value='For Negotiation'>For Negotiation</option>"+
                        "<option value='For Barangay Court'>For Barangay Court</option>"+   
                        "<option value='For Litigation'>For Litigation</option>"+  
                "</select></td>" +
                "</tr>";
                $("#editable tbody").append(tr_strs);
            }
        }
        });
```

and here the jquery ajax to send to php, and i think this is where the problem

```
$(document).on("click", "#saveclassi", function(){
  var tabol =   $('#editable tbody');
  tabol.find("tr").each(function (i){
    var $tds = $(this).find('td');
    // alert($tds.eq(0).text());
   $.ajax({
            url: "editclasfromtable.php",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "post",
            data:{branchedit: $("#branchedit").val(),datetoday: $("#datetoday").val(),sayt:2,
            memberid: $tds.eq(0).text(),seccure: $("#brselect").val(),
            about: $("#abawt").val(),whattodo: $("#wattodo").val(),wentodo: $("#whentodo").val(),
            colector: $("#colector").val(),remark: $("#remark").val(),classify: $("#coltype").val()
            },
            success: function(response){

            
            }
            
        });

  });
});
```

and my php to save or update all the rows, it works but it only update all data same using the first row. it will not loop on the second and so on. any help please

```
<?php
    require 'connection.php';
    if($_POST["sayt"] == 2){
        $memid = $_POST["memberid"] + 0;
        $seccure = $_POST["seccure"];
        $about = $_POST["about"];
        $whattodo = $_POST["whattodo"];
        $wentodo = $_POST["wentodo"];
        $colector = $_POST["colector"];
        $remark = $_POST["remark"];
        $classify = $_POST["classify"];
        
        $sql = "UPDATE members SET security='$seccure',classification='$about',remarks='$remark',collecting='$whattodo',collector='$colector',whentodo='$wentodo',recomendation='$classify' WHERE member_id='$memid'";
        // Prepare statement
        $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
        // execute the query
        $stmt->execute();

    }

?>
```

Comment: IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document. You are violating that, by creating elements with the same ID multiple times over in a loop.

Comment: @CBroe how do i fix it, the rows of memberid: $tds.eq(0).text() are unique that is the id of a mysql table